# Choosing CRS / PROJ4 string for EURO-Cordex rotated pole projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, sf

I have to analyze some CORDEX models which have a rotated pole projection. 
The projection is described in [this document](https://is-enes-data.github.io/cordex_archive_specifications.pdf), see page 10, Table 1, row "Europe high res".

I have tried to describe the proj4 string like so: `+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162.0 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +lat_0=0`, but it seems that this is not correct, at least using `sf` in `R`:

```
st_crs(rsf) <- "+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162.0 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +lat_0=0"
Warning message:
In CPL_crs_from_proj4string(x) :
  Cannot import crs from PROJ.4 string `+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162.0 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +lat_0=0', missing crs returned
```

What is the correct CRS for this projection?

Comment: There is very valuable answer from Patrick Brown. The correct CRS is `+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=0 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=18 +to_meter=0.01745329`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of Edzer and others we conjured a solution that works. See the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/651). It is a workaround and is not the most beautiful approach, but it works.

Basically using the `proj.4 crs` `"+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +to_meter=0.01745329"` works, with the caveat of using R `lwgeom` to project instead of `sf::st_transform`, since GDAL currently does not understand this projection (it will in the next version).

```
# d is the input dataset saved in an sf object
x <- lwgeom::st_transform_proj(d, c(st_crs(4326)$proj4string, "+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +to_meter=0.01745329"))
sf:st_crs(x) = NA # ?! This is mandatory for some reason
sf::st_crs(x) = 4326
sf::plot(x, axes = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This proj4 string isn't accepted in QGIS. Any idea why? QGIS doesn't give much detail.. just "The proj4 definition of 'CORDEX EUR-44' is not valid." ... Maybe a better question: Which version of GDAL was "the next version", when you posted this?

Comment: @naught101 as you can see in R I had some issues as well, I have no idea what's the issue with this proj4 string. I _think_ the version of GDAL I talk about was going to be GDAL3.0, but I might be wrong

Comment: OK, well I'm stuck on 2.4 for the time being. Maybe I will try and upgrade.. Any idea if there's a simple way to test the validity of a proj4 string?

Comment: @naught101 I'm sure there are several ways; google returns for example this: https://rdrr.io/github/lbusett/MODIStsp/man/check_proj4string.html, but try `man proj` for a more direct way using the command line proj program (on Unix).

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler approach is to use the "terra" package to open the nc or raster files and then assign the projection.

```
library(terra)

# Upload data where d is the input dataset in a nc or raster object
     x <- terra::rast("d")

# Define projection    
    crs<-"+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +to_meter=0.01745329"

# Change projection    
    x <- project(x, crs)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this (using terra 1.5-12) but got the following error : Error: [project] cannot create dataset from source In addition: Warning message: The NETCDF driver does not support update access to existing datasets. (GDAL error 6).  
Would it be the same to do: terra::crs(x) <- "+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +to_meter=0.01745329"?

Comment: Yep. It should be the same.                                                                                              ## S4 replacement method for signature 'SpatRaster'
crs(x)<-value

Comment: Thank you! When I plot the resulting raster, I got it with the wrong extent and axis labels (the same as plotting the raw raster). Thus, looks like the terra::crs(x) is not working or I am missing something?

Comment: It seems to be related to the version. I am using terra version 1.2-5

Comment: Yes. It is working with terra 1.2-5. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My file had the following metadata `gdal_metadata(file1)`

```
[29] "rotated_pole#grid_mapping_name=rotated_latitude_longitude"
[30] "rotated_pole#grid_north_pole_latitude=31.75831245449315"
[31] "rotated_pole#grid_north_pole_longitude=87.59703130293302"           
[32] "rotated_pole#north_pole_grid_longitude=0"
```

everything worked with the following proj4 string

```
paste0("+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=", 0,
                " +o_lat_p=", 31.75831245449315, 
                " +lon_0=", 87.59703130293302-180,
                " +to_meter=0.01745329")
```