# Handling raster data in a "rotated pole projection" with R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proj, grib

My question is about using R to transform raster data from a rotated pole projection to a regular latlon grid - and then plotting it.

I am working with data from a numerical weather model, which is specified in a rotated latlon grid - I do this entirely in R. The data is provided in grib format, which is easily read with "raster" package. As example data, I have a grib file in a format identical to the weather data but with ground elevation values for my area of interest (Denmark and southern Sweden) - [(example data available here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd5av2moli1q8kq/dk_geopotential_nwpruc?dl=0).

Loading and plotting the data looks like:

```
library("raster")

geopotential <- raster(dk_geopotential_file)

plot(geopotential,
     xlab="Longtitude (rotated)",ylab="Lattitude (rotated)")
```

[image: Elevation data in the rotated latlon grid.]

This looks good - shapes of Denmark and Sweden is clearly seen. Asking for the crs information (as a proj4 string) of the rotated grid gives:

```
> crs(geopotential)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +a=6367470 +b=6367470 +no_defs
```

Now I want to transform this into a regular WGS84 lat-lon format of the type:

```
"+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

I would normally do this with the projectRaster function:

```
geopotential_wgs84 <- projectRaster(geopotential,
                                    crs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ")
```

But nothing happens! The data remains in the rotated latlon grid.
I have tried following these two threads ([here](https://proj.maptools.narkive.com/Yb9d1acW/proj4-specifications-for-a-rotated-latlon-grid-on-a-sphere) and [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/651)), and played around with "ob_tran" arguments (Oblique Transformation).

[Choosing CRS / PROJ4 string for EURO-Cordex rotated pole projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272483) seems to do this for a shapefile with the sf package, but I can't make it work with my raster data.

In my case, the coordinates of the geographic *South Pole* (not the North Pole as in the two linked threads) in the rotated grid is: (lon;lat) = (3;-40).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will need to include the transformation in the reprojection. Did you happen to see this post? They finally got it in the end using R:

[eCRS for rotated pole projection works with rgdal, but not with sf #651](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/651)

Comment: Yes, I have been following that post as well. But as I understand, they use vector data and not raster data there? The closest I have gotten to something reasonable is by setting `crs(geopotential) <- "+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-177 +o_lat_p=40 +lon_0=180 +to_meter=0.01745329"` but the final output from the `projectRaster`-call still isn't near the regular lonlat coordinates for Denmark