# Rotate coordinates from climatic data in raster format (cordex-EU domain 11) to usual coordinate systems

Tags: coordinate-system, r, netcdf, climate

I am trying to create a dataset that shows future climatic condition in Europe aggregates to NUT2 administration level in R. To do so, i work with cordex data (domain EU 11), that is coming withrotated coordinates.

I used the data hurs_EUR-11_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_day_20310101-20351231.nc (data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v1bKBUzBI3Pu6E3N_cmJjoiftWB2OAwS/view?usp=sharing) ) which is the relative humidity 
Its looks as follows :

> ```
>  6 variables (excluding dimension variables):
>     double height[]   
>         axis: Z
>         long_name: height
>         positive: up
>         standard_name: height
>         units: m
>     double time_bnds[bnds,time]   
>     char rotated_pole[]   
>         grid_mapping_name: rotated_latitude_longitude
>         grid_north_pole_latitude: 39.25
>         grid_north_pole_longitude: -162
>     float hurs[rlon,rlat,time]   
>         grid_mapping: rotated_pole
>         _FillValue: 1.00000002004088e+20
>         missing_value: 1.00000002004088e+20
>         standard_name: relative_humidity
>         long_name: Near-Surface Relative Humidity
>         units: %
>         coordinates: lon lat height
>         cell_methods: time: mean
>     double lon[rlon,rlat]   
>         standard_name: longitude
>         long_name: longitude
>         units: degrees_east
>     double lat[rlon,rlat]   
>         standard_name: latitude
>         long_name: latitude
>         units: degrees_north
> ```

```
 4 dimensions:
    time  Size:1826   *** is unlimited ***
        standard_name: time
        units: days since 1949-12-01 00:00:00
        calendar: standard
        long_name: time
        bounds: time_bnds
        axis: T
    bnds  Size:2
```

> [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272483/choosing-crs-proj4-string-for-euro-cordex-rotated-pole-projection) "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for
>   dimension named bnds BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will
>   probably fail at this point"
>           rlon  Size:424
>               standard_name: grid_longitude
>               long_name: longitude in rotated pole grid
>               units: degrees
>               axis: X
>           rlat  Size:412
>               standard_name: grid_latitude
>               long_name: latitude in rotated pole grid
>               units: degrees
>               axis: Y

First, i created an array

```
hurs.array <- ncvar_get(data2, "hurs")
```

Then i create a grid with the projection as suggested in this post
[Choosing CRS / PROJ4 string for EURO-Cordex rotated pole projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272483/choosing-crs-proj4-string-for-euro-cordex-rotated-pole-projection) 
Note that the issue raised about this post in about an simple feature and not about raster.

```
r_brick <- brick(hurs.array, xmn=min(lat), xmx=max(lat), ymn=min(lon), ymx=max(lon), crs=CRS("+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162.0 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +lat_0=0"))
```

Now my question is  how to transform this data into the EU projection? 
with

```
r_brickP<- projectRaster(r_brick, crs="+init=epsg:3035")
```

I get

> not finiteno non-missing arguments to min;

What is going on?

Is this the right approach?

Is there a better approach to unrotate the data?

If yes which one?

What is my most efficient way to then perform a zonal statics with as layer with epsg:3035 projection?

I also tried the function rotate, but i got a line suggesting that this is not this method was not appropriate.

Comment: Note to anyone contemplating this - the data is 399Mb

Comment: What are your `lon` and `lat` whenyou make the brick? To correctly specify the extent of your brick they need to be in transformed coordinates, not true lat-long.

Comment: @Spacedman, i guess i have not transformed them, i just used the max and min from the rlong and rlat...

Comment: so i dont seem to be able to get at the bottom of this. How do i transform these coordinate correctly, and in one go for the whole stack?

Comment: The `lon` and `lat` variables in the netCDF appear to be the correct EPSG 4326 lat-long coordinates (features in the humidity match map features from OpenStreetMap). If the `rlon` and `rlat` variables are the X and Y coords of the grid system, we need to find the transform that turns those into `lon` and `lat`. If that fails you can work with a set of {lon, lat, h} points rather than a raster (but sloooow).

Comment: If the extent of the brick must be in transformed coordinates, shouldn't say `xmn=min(rlat), xmx=max(rlat), ymn=min(rlon), ymx=max(rlon)` ? Also, the PROJ string for the CRS shouldn't be `"+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162.0 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=162.0"` ?