# Reprojecting NetCDF naming data from rotated pole coordinate system to WGS84 in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, coordinates, netcdf

I am using data from [UKCP Local Projections at 2.2km Resolution](https://data.ceda.ac.uk/badc/ukcp18/data/land-cpm/uk/2.2km/rcp85/01/tas/mon/v20210615). The data does not have any stored coordinate reference system. However, the associated documentation explains that UKCP use rotated pole coordinate system with following attributes:

- Rotated Pole
- Grid North Pole latitude = 37.5
- Grid North Pole longitude = 177.5

For my data analysis, I need to convert this data to WGS84. I have read multiple threads at different sites but I could'nt figure out how I can fix this issue.

Here is my code:

```r
# load libraries
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
library(rgdal)
#> Please note that rgdal will be retired by the end of 2023,
#> plan transition to sf/stars/terra functions using GDAL and PROJ
#> at your earliest convenience.
#> 
#> rgdal: version: 1.5-28, (SVN revision 1158)
#> Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
#> Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29
#> Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/mohsi/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/gdal
#> GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
#> Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 7.2.1, January 1st, 2021, [PJ_VERSION: 721]
#> Path to PROJ shared files: C:/Users/mohsi/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/proj
#> PROJ CDN enabled: FALSE
#> Linking to sp version:1.4-6
#> To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
#> use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading sp or rgdal.
#> Overwritten PROJ_LIB was C:/Users/mohsi/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/rgdal/proj
library(sp)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# netcdf file info
gI <- GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc")
#> Warning in getProjectionRef(x, OVERRIDE_PROJ_DATUM_WITH_TOWGS84 =
#> OVERRIDE_PROJ_DATUM_WITH_TOWGS84, : Discarded datum unknown in Proj4 definition:
#> +proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +lon_0=357.5 +o_lon_p=0 +o_lat_p=37.5 +R=6371229
#> +no_defs
#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): GeoTransform values not available
#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver

#> Warning in GDALinfo("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-
#> cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc"): statistics not supported by this driver
attr(gI, "mdata")[grep("^tas", attr(gI, "mdata"))]
#>  [1] "tas#cell_methods=time: mean"                                                   
#>  [2] "tas#coordinates=ensemble_member_id latitude longitude month_number year yyyymm"
#>  [3] "tas#description=Mean air temperature"                                          
#>  [4] "tas#grid_mapping=rotated_latitude_longitude"                                   
#>  [5] "tas#label_units=Â°C"                                                           
#>  [6] "tas#long_name=Mean air temperature"                                            
#>  [7] "tas#plot_label=Mean air temperature at 1.5m (Â°C)"                             
#>  [8] "tas#standard_name=air_temperature"                                             
#>  [9] "tas#units=degC"                                                                
#> [10] "tas#_FillValue=1e+020"
attr(gI, "mdata")[grep("^rotated", attr(gI, "mdata"))]
#> [1] "rotated_latitude_longitude#earth_radius=6371229"                        
#> [2] "rotated_latitude_longitude#grid_mapping_name=rotated_latitude_longitude"
#> [3] "rotated_latitude_longitude#grid_north_pole_latitude=37.5"               
#> [4] "rotated_latitude_longitude#grid_north_pole_longitude=177.5"             
#> [5] "rotated_latitude_longitude#longitude_of_prime_meridian=0"               
#> [6] "rotated_latitude_longitude#north_pole_grid_longitude=0"

# "+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=177.5 +o_lat_p=37.5 +lon_0=180 +ellps=sphere +no_defs"


# load data
r <- raster::brick("C:/Users/mohsi/Downloads/weather proj data/tas_rcp85_land-cpm_uk_2.2km_15_mon_202012-202111.nc",
                   stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE)
#> Loading required namespace: ncdf4
#> Warning in .getCRSfromGridMap4(atts): cannot process these parts of the crs:
#> grid_north_pole_latitude=37.5
#> grid_north_pole_longitude=177.5
#> north_pole_grid_longitude=0
#> Warning in .getCRSfromGridMap4(atts): cannot create a valid crs
#> grid_mapping_name; false_easting; false_northing; scale_factor_at_projection_origin; scale_factor_at_central_meridian; standard_parallel; standard_parallel1; standard_parallel2; longitude_of_central_meridian; longitude_of_projection_origin; latitude_of_projection_origin; straight_vertical_longitude_from_pole; longitude_of_prime_meridian; semi_major_axis; semi_minor_axis; inverse_flattening; earth_radius; +proj; +x_0; +y_0; +k_0; +k_0; +lat_1; +lat_1; +lat_2; +lon_0; +lon_0; +lat_0; +lon_0; +pm; +a; +b; +rf; +a

# setting crs
raster::crs(r) <- "+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=177.5 +o_lat_p=37.5 +lon_0=180 +to_meter=0.01745329"
plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
# reprojecting to WGS84

ss <- projectRaster(r, crs="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
plot(ss)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Can anyone tell how I can transform this data to WGS84 system?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272483/choosing-crs-proj4-string-for-euro-cordex-rotated-pole-projection might help. Otherwise the transformed true lat-long coordinates are in the NetCDF and can be got using the `netcdf4` package.

Comment: @Spacedman I had tried this but could not solve the issue. However, I found a blog that helped me to fix it. I'll share it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this following code in this blog post:

https://luciazwatts.wordpress.com/2020/07/27/how-to-using-met-office-ukcp18-2-2km-climate-projections/

If someone else is using UKCP data struggling with reprojecting it to WGS84, check this link out.