# Reprojecting raster or vector CRS and extracting raster values based on vector boundaries

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, proj, sf

I am working with a EUR-11 CORDEX dataset of daily temperature values (nc file) from ESGF database and EUROSTAT NUTS data (from here: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts) as my shp file for the EU-countrie's borders.

My goal is to extract raster values from the nc file based on the polygons in the shp file.

```
    library(sf)
    library(ncdf4)
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)
    library(lwgeom)

    # vector data    
    NUTS_data <- st_read("./data/NUTS_RG_60M_2016_4326/NUTS_RG_60M_2016_4326.shp")
        NUTS2 <- subset(NUTS_data,LEVL_CODE == 2)
        idx <- c("FRY1","FRY2","FRY3","FRY4","FRY5","ES70", "PT30","PT20") #getting rid of some small islands outside my study area
        for(i in 1:length(idx)){
          NUTS2 <- subset(NUTS2,NUTS_ID != idx[i])
        }
        EUstates = NUTS2 %>%
          group_by(CNTR_CODE) %>%
          summarize(
            urban  = sum(URBN_TYPE)) 
        EUstates <- EUstates[,c(1,3)]
    
    crs(EUstates)
        
    Coordinate Reference System:
    Deprecated Proj.4 representation: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
    Warning:
    In wkt(x) : CRS object has no comment

    # raster data
    file <- "tas_EUR-11_MPI-M-MPI-ESM-LR_historical_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1a_3hr_199801010000-199812312100.nc" 
    ncfile <- nc_open(file)
    lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid ="lon")
    lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid="lat")
    TdmEUR98 <- ncvar_get(ncfile, varid="tas") 
    TymEUR98 <- rowMeans(TdmEUR98,na.rm = T,dims=2) # Calculate yearmean
    data <- as.data.frame(TymEUR98)
    r <- raster(t(data),xmn=min(lon),xmx=max(lon),ymn=min(lat),ymx=max(lat),
                              crs=CRS("+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +o_lon_p=-162 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180 +to_meter=0.01745329")) 
    r <- flip(r, direction="y")
    r.clip <- mask(r,EUstates)
```

The CRS for the raster is from the Q&A at [Choosing CRS / PROJ4 string for EURO-Cordex rotated pole projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272483/choosing-crs-proj4-string-for-euro-cordex-rotated-pole-projection)
Before I load my data in R, I preprocess the CORDEX data with CDO, calculating daily means from those 3h values and remapping the rotated pole projection to a regular lonlat grid.

When I plot my raster and vector, it looks good so far.

```
plot(r.clip)
plot(EUstates,col="transparent",add=T)
```

[image]

I am aware, that the CRS of my raster and vector differ up to this point, but they seem to match visually, so I just tried to extract...which did not work. ext contains only Values of NULL and NA

```
ext <- extract(r, EUstates, method='simple')
# Warning:
In .local(x, y, ...) :
  Transforming SpatialPolygons to the crs of the Raster
```

Trying to reproject both CRS as follwing did not get me anywhere either, because the raster and shp now don't align and the longitude and latitude seem off.

```
CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # as CRS 4326 seems to already be the projection of shp file
v <- st_transform_proj(EUstates,"+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
r.rep <- projectRaster(r.clip,crs = crs(v))
plot(r.rep)
plot(v,col="transparent",add=T)
```

[image]

I assume I have to change something about the projection or reproject my raster and/or my shp file, but I tried reprojecting both an I just can't get it right. So at this point I am just lost and don't really know what to do.